# Connecting Metamask to private blockchain in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, ethereum, geth, metamask

I'm trying to connect to rpc in Metamask. Metamask keeps idling in the trying to connect unknown private network.
Geth is running in a Linux Azure network.
Its public IP is *AzureIP*
Im sshing into the server, then I run the following command:

```
geth --identity “TestNode” --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testprivareDir --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 console
```

I get the following output among other things:

```
HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I then run `miner.start()`

I try to connect to this private network in Metamask by going to custom RPC and putting the address http://*AzureIP*:8080

And it just idles there. In azure I have the following network inbound port rules 
[image]

From my own laptop (not sshed into the server) I then run the command:

```
ping http://*AzureIP*:8080
```

And I get Request timeout for icmp_seq ...

How can I fix this or any advice to connect to the private network?

Comment: Hi, does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is a loop address, the service only works inside VM.

On your scenario, you need listen the service on `0.0.0.0` on VM's private IP. You could add `--rpcaddr "10.0.0.4"`.

```
geth --identity “TestNode” --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpcaddr "10.0.0.4" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir testprivareDir --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 console
```

Comment: Hi, in fact, you question like this [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2982) on Github. You could check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully connected to the server private chain in a format like this: geth --identity "xxx" --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir /home/xxx --port "30303" --rpcapi "db,eth,personal,net,web3" --networkid xxx --targetgaslimit xxx,you can try it

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things And also illustrate your answer